# How to set "Html.SomeHelper" attribute value to be equal to model property name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper, c#-6.0

I have form model and I want to use property name as value for some form field attributes. What would be the best way for that? (In this case, I would like to have *id="PropertyName"*).

```
// FormViewModel
[Display(Name = "First name*")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

// Index.cshtml
<form id="form1" asp-controller="controller" asp-action="Index" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new
   {
     @id = "firstName",
     @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
   })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
 </div>
</form>
```

tnx!

Comment: as in `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new
   {
     @id = Model.FirstName,
     @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
   })` ?

Comment: @Theo,  yes, just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @teo van kot said, MVC does that by default. But, if path to your property is something like model.Submodel.PropertyName, ID attribute will be "Submodel_PropertyName". If you want just "PropertyName", then this extension method/wrapper can be used:

```cs
public static class Extension method
{
    public static IHtmlContent CustomTextBoxFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression)
    {
        // very simple implementation, can fail if expression is not as expected!

        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if(body == null) throw new Exception("Expression refers to a method, not a property");

        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, null, new { id = body.Member.Name, placeholder = helper.DisplayNameFor(expression)  });
    }
}
```

in the razor view output will be like this:

```
@Html.CustomTextBoxFor(x => x.Foo)
<input id="Foo" name="Foo" type="text" placeholder="Foo" value="">

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo)
<input id="Foo" name="Foo" type="text" value="">

@Html.CustomTextBoxFor(x => x.AnotherModel.Foo)
<input id="Foo" name="AnotherModel.Foo" type="text" placeholder="Foo"  value="">

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnotherModel.Foo)
<input id="AnotherModel_Foo" name="AnotherModel.Foo" type="text" value="">
```

Problem with first and third approach, so using this technique, if you have same property name on several places in the model:

```
@Html.CustomTextBoxFor(x => x.DeliveryAddress.StreetName)
@Html.CustomTextBoxFor(x => x.BillingAddress.StreetName)
```

both input tags will have the same ID attribute!

Examples are written for MVC6, MVC5 uses different HtmlHelper types.

Answer (score 0):

You just shouldn't escape your `placeholder` property like this:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new
   {
     @id = "firstName",
     placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
   })
```

Also there is no need in `@id = "firstName"` strongly typed helpers add `id` attribute with Property name by default, so it will be like this in your case:

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new
   {
     placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the coment above, it looks like the solution you are seeking is this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, 
new { @id = Model.FirstName, 
@placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName) 
})
```

But I'd say there's definitely a code smell there ... that is a very odd thing to do.